# How does gcc linker decide which libc to link as per 32bit/64bit difference?

Tags: gcc, linker, 64-bit, ld

-lc links with libc, but -m will specify whether it should be 32 or 64bit.

My question is, does gcc or ld decide which libc.so should be the correct library to link with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compile something using GCC and add verbosity options. You'll then see that gcc passes the libc path to LD. GCC has the path hard-coded in, but it can be overridden with some -W parameter.

Note that LD obviously still needs to know if it is to generate a 32-bit or 64-bit binary, but the libc path doesn't come from -m but is passed separately.